# Windows API Return Code Values

Tags: .net, winapi

I am developping a small program based on the .Net framework 4 and by using the C# language.
I am using a .Net library which itself uses functions from the AVIFile Windows API.

I have got an error when using the AVIStreamRead function.
Here is the MSDN documentation for the AVIStreamRead function :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756849(v=vs.85).aspx

I want to get more information about my error from the result integer value.
The documentation page lists the three following return codes :

- AVIERR_BUFFERTOOSMALL
- AVIERR_MEMORY
- AVIERR_FILEREAD

But where do I get the corresponding integer values ?

Comment: They are defined (somewhere) in your project (or in the 3rd party libraries you're including).  Capture the result and compare against the known error values to see how to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can get them from Vfw.h.

```
#define AVIERR_UNSUPPORTED      MAKE_AVIERR(101)
#define AVIERR_BADFORMAT        MAKE_AVIERR(102)
#define AVIERR_MEMORY           MAKE_AVIERR(103)
#define AVIERR_INTERNAL         MAKE_AVIERR(104)
...
```

To convert SCODE to error code you can use

```
WORD SCODE_CODE(SCODE sc);
```

Comment: Thanks four your answer. But which Windows DLL offers the SCODE_CODE function. I have googled for a while but without success.

Comment: Check this link, please, http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687314(v=vs.85).aspx In the bottom of MSDN page there is information about requirements, header files and dlls they need (in your case header you need is winerror.h) It is common format for WinAPI description in MSDN. So, if you have a problem to find a header look at this section first.